# Executing javascript code stored in an element attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

say there is an element #button with the attribute onmousedown containing some random javascript how could I trigger the js in that element attribute using jQuery?

```
j("#otherbutton").click(function(){ 
         var script =  j("#button").attr("onmousedown"); //what now? 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or `j("#button").trigger("mousedown");` which will execute the code in the `onmousedown` attribute *and* any event handlers attached to the "mousedown" event.

Comment: woa, the answer was in my question :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
eval(script);
```

> The eval() function evaluates and/or
>   executes a string of JavaScript code.
>
> First, eval() determines if the
>   argument is a valid string, then
>   eval() parses the string looking for
>   JavaScript code. If it finds any
>   JavaScript code, it will be executed.
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Answer (score -1):

You can use the js [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function.

```
document.write("<br />" + eval("2+2"));
```

the eval will execute the string script..